# What are the default font sizes (in pixels) for the html heading tags (<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, etc.)?

Tags: html

What are the default font pixel sizes for the heading (h1-h6) tags?

Comment: This is not meaningless.  There are default sizes that vary from one heading tag to the next, and it is legitimate to ask what those sizes are,

Comment: Which of the 321,219,449 different browsers/version/OS permutations are you asking for exactly?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think it is as follows:

```
h1 is 2 em
h2 is 1.5 em
h3 is 1.3 em
h4 is 1 em
h5 is 0.8 em
h6 is 0.7 em
```

An em is not the same as a pixel. It is a relative way of looking at sizes. With that said I think most browsers default to 16px (or 1em).

Comment: Sam Benson's reply answers the original question about sizing in pixels.

Comment: The values for `h3`, `h5` and `h6` are outdated, see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70720104/214446).

Answer (score 73):

Another way of putting it is:

```
h1 is   32px   (2em)
h2 is   24px (1.5em)
h3 is 20.8px (1.3em)
h4 is   16px   (1em)
h5 is 12.8px (0.8em)
h6 is 11.2px (0.7em)
```

Comment: The values for `h3`, `h5` and `h6` are outdated, see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70720104/214446).

Answer (score 17):

This is set in the browser's default stylesheet. As of 2023, modern browsers all set these to the same em values. And by default 1em is 16px in modern browsers, thus:

```
h1 | 2em    | 32px
h2 | 1.5em  | 24px
h3 | 1.17em | 18.72px
h4 | 1em    | 16px
h5 | 0.83em | 13.28px
h6 | 0.67em | 10.72px
```

These values are what the [WhatWG's living standard recommends](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#sections-and-headings) and I checked that Chrome, Firefox and Safari indeed implement these values.

(Note that the values for h5 and h6 are slightly different than in the legacy [default style sheet for HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html)).

Finally, you can run the following snippet and inspect in your browser of choice:

```html
<h1>h1</h1>
<h2>h2</h2>
<h3>h3</h3>
<h4>h4</h4>
<h5>h5</h5>
<h6>h6</h6>
```

Answer (score 10):

For an actual proof, take a look at the html.css (171 - 237) with the default style of Mozilla Firefox:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.17em;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.00em;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 0.83em;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 0.67em;
}
```

The whole css is:

```
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-block-start: .67em;
  margin-block-end: .67em;
}

h2,
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-block-start: .83em;
  margin-block-end: .83em;
}

h3,
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.17em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
}

h4,
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.00em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-block-start: 1.33em;
  margin-block-end: 1.33em;
}

h5,
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.83em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-block-start: 1.67em;
  margin-block-end: 1.67em;
}

h6,
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
:-moz-any(article, aside, nav, section)
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.67em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-block-start: 2.33em;
  margin-block-end: 2.33em;
}
```

Comment: That is right. check this. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html

Comment: On a 16-pixel scale, that's:

h1: 32px,

h2: 24px,

h3: 18⅔px,

h4: 16px,

h5: 13⅓px,

h6: 10⅔px.

On a 12-pixel scale, that's:

h1: 24px,

h2: 18px,

h3: 14px,

h4: 12px,

h5: 10px,

h6: 8px

Answer (score 3):

Size for h1 - h6 tags are different from browser to browser. There is no W3 spec that enforces standard size for heading tags. Each browser has implemented its own.

It is recommended to use a CSS normalizer to make the sizes uniform across all the browsers. You can do this by defining your custom sizes for the tags to override the default browser values.

Comment: Actually, they are the same on every current major browser.