# font size changes when div height is set or with long text, only on smartphone

Tags: android, html, css

I have noticed a very strange behavior.

On desktop, with the following codes, the font-size is always consistent.

But on smart phone (I have tested it with firefox and chrome on android), I observe the following:

1) Here the first text is bigger than the second one.

```
<div style="width:560px;margin:auto;font-size:20px">
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    <div style="height:20px">
        bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

2) Here, they are both small (I have only shortened the fist text)

```
<div style="width:560px;margin:auto;font-size:20px">
    bla bla
    <div style="height:20px">
        bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

3) Here, they are both big (I have removed the `style="height:20px"`)

```
<div style="width:560px;margin:auto;font-size:20px">
    bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
    <div>
        bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

That does not make sense to me, could some one explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some meta-tags are required for mobile development, which might be causing your issues:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scaleable=no, width=device-width" />
```

The solution to this question could also help you out:

[best practice font size for mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174669/best-practice-font-size-for-mobile)