# Best font size for readability on smartphones?

Tags: css

What is the best font size (web) for iphones, nexus and the most commons smartphones? 16px like desktop computers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174669/best-practice-font-size-for-mobile

Answer (score -1):

It depends on screen sizes.
Below are the sevral font sizes for diffrent screen sizes.

(min-width: 858px) 
font-size: 12px

(min-width: 780px)
 font-size: 11px;

(min-width: 702px)

```
    font-size: 10px;
```

(min-width: 724px) 
 font-size: 9px;

(max-width: 623px)
font-size: 8px;

Comment: On which source are based theses values?

Comment: @RobinKomiwes: They are from [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140330054852/http://responsivenews.co.uk/post/13925578846/fluid-grids-orientation-resolution-independence)