# Wrong size when setting size for h1 using em

Tags: css, font-size

I have h1 tag, and I tried to set the font-size for this tag using em, but instead of going larger, it became smaller. Below is my code:

```css
h1{
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is a title</h1>
  <p>hello this is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
```

As noticed in my code, after removing the 1.2em, it becomes larger again. From my understanding, 1em = the current font size of the page. making 2em should make it double the size. 1.2em should make it a bit bigger, but for me here it's making it smaller. How does em work in this case?

Comment: `em` is a unit of measure just like `px` however it is relative to its containing element. http://pxtoem.com/ , https://jsfiddle.net/eb0uv5LL/ is working as expected, so i assume you have some other css on your page? perhaps bootstrap?

Comment: Hi, even in your jsfiddle example, setting 1.2em should make it bigger, right? it should be 1.2 the original size, yet the h1 is smaller.

Comment: as you say in your question `em` is based upon the `body` (or containing element's size), thus changing the size of `h1` you are overriding its default. If you put a `span` inside the `h1` with an `1.2em` you'd get what you're after i believe, updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eb0uv5LL/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct regarding the definition, but there is also a default style, and the `em` is related to the font-size of the parent-element that has a fixed size (or the `body` element if no other element has fixed size).

Here is an example:

```css
body {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.container h1{
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.container2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.container3 {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>text - 13px</div>
<h1>title 1 - 26px (default to 2em == 13*2 = 26px)</h1>
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is a title - 15.6px (1.2em == 13*1.2 = 15.6px)</h1>
  <p>hello this is a paragraph - 13px</p>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <h1>Another title - 40px (parent is 20px, default is 2em, 2*20 == 40px)</h1>
</div>
<div class="container3">
  <h1>3rd title - 13px (parent is 13px*0.5(em) == 6.5, default h1 is 2em, 2*6.5px == 13px)</h1>
</div>
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems):

> Ems
>   Another way of setting the font size is with em values. **The size of an em value is dynamic**. When defining the font-size property, an em is equal to the size of the font that applies to the parent of the element in question. If you haven't set the font size anywhere on the page, **then it is the browser default, which is often 16px**. So, by default 1em = 16px, and 2em = 32px. If you set a font-size of 20px on the body element, then 1em = 20px and 2em = 40px. Note that the value 2 is essentially a multiplier of the current em size.

Comment: How do you know the default em for the elements?

Comment: @Jacky, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6140504/648350 typical sizes of browser default headings

Comment: Another option - right-click on the element. inspect the element and check the user-agent values :)

Comment: I could check it in browser as well .thank you. So just to know. it always takes for the <body> tag? What if I set the size on another container, will it pick it or it only looks at the <body> tag?  

For example if I have <body> <div> then <h1> will 1.2 be related to the div or the <body> tag?

Comment: @Jacky, related to the `div`, if you always want to reference the body, have a look at using `rem` instead of `em`, https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/

Comment: Updated the explanation (with better example). Check now.

Comment: i heard 1em = 16px

Comment: @JishnuVS,  No,  there is no "hard" definition for that. Browsers can have the default set to 16px, but can also set the default other values.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the page `em` is `16px`  - so `1.2em` is equal to `19px`.

The default `h1` of a page is `2em` or equal to `32px`.

So by changing the value as you have, it will decrease the natural size of the `h1`.

Comment: Where do I find out the default em for the page?

Comment: You can set the page or `body` font size using `body{font-size:16px}`  but browsers use 16px as the default size if none is specified.

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding, 1em = the current font size of the page

That's not true. You are confusing `em` with `rem`, which is the computed `font-size` of the root element.

`em` is the computed `font-size` of the element on which it is used.

But of course this can't work when you use `em` units on `font-size` itself, that would be a circular definition. In that case, `em` refers to the computed `font-size` of the parent element.

Then, if for example `h1` are styled with `font-size: 2em` by default in the user agent stylesheet, if you override that with `font-size: 1.2em`, it will become smaller!