# How to set up font size for DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, font-size, dropdown

I have the dropdownlist in the razor code.

```
<div class="col-right">
                @{
                    List<string> Country = new List<string>();
                    Country.Add("Englind");
                    Country.Add("Spanish");
                }
                @Html.DropDownList("Country", new SelectList(Country).ToList())
            </div>
```

What I want is to set the item size in the dropdown is h3. How?

**EDIT:**

I followed the answer to set up the size as 24, but it selected the size 13.

[image: Style]

Comment: I created this for you [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YnjOnI)

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid, please see my EDIT. I am not sure why the font size style is not applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use new attribute in your html helper like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Country", new SelectList(Country).ToList(), new { @style= "font-size: 24px;" })
```

Comment: I just need h3. Is h3 style is 10px?

Comment: @Bigeyes h3 font size is 24px. see https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_fonts.asp

Comment: The link is broken. And I heard that it is depend on the browser.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140430/what-are-the-most-common-font-sizes-for-h1-h6-tags?

Comment: @Bigeyes Yes, but It can be customized depending on your browser or website.

Comment: I don't know why the size is not changed at all even I set the size as 80. Maybe `<div class="col-right">` controls the size?

Comment: @Bigeyes you can use `font-size: 24px; !important` for this.

Comment: @Bigeyes The `Html.DropDownList()` method generates a `select` element. There is a `app.sccs` in your website or project that it affects all `select` by `13px !important`. You have to take `line 203` in it if need to `24px`.