# Unexpected font size of textarea using rem in Chrome when setting root element font size to percentage

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-size

When setting the root `font-size` to `62.5%` or any other percentage, Chrome renders the `textarea` font size as `16.25px`. I expected it to be `20px` just like the `div` font size is being rendered. Also, in Firefox, both the `div` and `textarea` are rendering at `20px`. I'm a bit confused as to why this would be in Chrome. Shouldn't the `rem` value be consistently based on the root element?

Note that setting the root element `font-size` to a fixed pixel amount, things work as expected.

By the way, I'm on Windows 10 and am unsure if this happens on Mac. Also, I suppose I can switch to using pixels, however I was hoping to use the percentage based size so I can keep the user font size preference.

```html
<html style="font-size: 62.5%">
<body>
    <div style="font-size: 2rem">asdf</div>
    <textarea style="font-size: 2rem">asdf</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update:
When I change the font family on the root to anything other than monospace it seems to work find. Only with monospace this issue occurs. Still stumped on why this is happening...

```html
<html style="font-size: 62.5%">
<body>
    <div style="font-size: 2rem">asdf</div>
    <textarea style="font-size: 2rem; font-family: sans-serif">asdf</textarea> <!-- 20px -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using percentage so its not specific like pixels, So its normal if you see different values of size's in different browsers.
i suggest you use a font base and use rem or % on that and try to use pixels and media query for responsive...

Comment: Thanks, I guess I see why in different browsers it could be different. However, in my case even in the same browser, Chrome, the font size is different while still using the same rem value.

Comment: @Talha
Thats a little bit wierd but maybe the tag you are font-sizing it has default font-size and they affects on your font-size.
see the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410066/what-are-the-default-font-sizes-in-pixels-for-the-html-heading-tags-h1-h2
btw if its what you wanted please accept my answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks for helping @sm10 - Shouldn't when using rems the font sizing should be coming from the root element though?

Comment: @Talha YW bro, I think yes becaz if you check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_pxtoemconversion.asp you can see it say's "set your default font-size", So if you want to solve the problem use a font base(default) then rem or percentage will be logical.!
i use font base in my own projects and i highly recommend it to you, If you don't set a default size The browser goes like: 62.5% of what size? well we don't have any default So... (the browser makes its own default and its different in chrome, firefox, ie.)

Comment: @Talha This is the point i highlighted it for you:

PX to EM Converter
`Set a default font size (usually 16px)
Then, convert a pixel value to em, based on the default size`
Or, convert an em value to pixels, based on the default size

Comment: @Talha Pixel is a static measurement, while percent and EM are relative measurements.
relative means they are depended on their parents so they can also do changes.
as a verdict just use font-base(default).

Comment: thanks again, ill mark this as accepted. I guess the browser for some strange reason is just giving the textarea as a different base font size when using percentage. honestly i like the firefox implementation more b/c it is more consistent, but anyway as this is kind of an edge case all is good :).