# What font-size are commonly used for html and each element?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

I am decorating a website, but i don't even know what size of the font in HTML I should decide. Neither is the other elements. First of all, I will try to decide the size at px. After deciding a font-size of every element, I will try to calculate px to em.

I do not know when I should use rem, and em and what font-size I should decide the root in index.html.

Comment: It differs according to elements like <h1> to <h6> tags has other font-size, while <p> tags have other font size. In this other elements like <a> <span> have different font size.

Comment: Typically 16px .

Comment: 16px for p,li and for headers you can see what zurb foundation uses as default to get a general idea of defaults for mobile and desktop. https://get.foundation/sites/docs/typography-base.html#header-styles (Although it depends on your design as to what sizes you go with). Here is a post explaining the difference between em, rem and px. https://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/em-vs-rem-vs-px

Comment: @Twinkle Shama Thank you.

Comment: @B001  I set the font-size as a basic font-size on my website.

Comment: @WizardCoder I will check the reference websites you sent! Awesome!

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325877/7183675 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325916/7183675 for suggestions. Unfortunately it differs between browsers so no concrete answer

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a font-size you may find easy to work with.

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: ___; /* <= choose your own font */
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
h5 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Suc6 with your website.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with weather you use px or em or ren or pt, etc...?

Use **rem** unit which by defaults 16px (1rem = 16px) but it will be tedious to calculate value so as you know default font size of browser which is set on html which 16px and other elements in dom inherite that value so what you do is that change `html {font-size: 62.5%}` by doing this now 1rem is equal to 10px

```css
html {
font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
font-size: 1.6rem
}
```

> **Note** 16px is 100% default font size. If you set 62.5% as font size on html then now your default font-size will be 10px which is took small so **set font-size on body 1.6rem (which equal to 16px)** so that other element inherite it and there will be no change.

Now you can easily use rem unit instead of px .

> **Note** px value are fixed. Means that if screen get smaller then it will remain same. But rem units are relative units.

**Thank you**

Answer (score -1):

Typical what you want is the following:

```
<h1> - 32px - font-size: 2em 
<h2> - 24px - font-size: 1.5em 
<h3> - 18px - font-size: 1.17em 
<h4> - 16px - font-size: 1em 
<h5> - 13px - font-size: 0.83em 
<h6> - 10px - font-size: 0.67em
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will save the list!